# Arduino with multiple LEDs and timers

Tags: arduino, wireless, timer, time

I'm working on creating a wireless interval timer with an Arduino, is there a specific Arduino board required that can work with multiple LEDs and give me the programming capability for providing time, and having multiple timers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All Arduinos** and compatible boards can work with multiple LEDs, and have multiple timers.

For the programming capability of providing time, which presumably means a precision real-time clock, battery-backed RTC clock ICs and ready-to-use modules are ubiquitous and inexpensive. Connecting one to the Arduino is simple, and libraries are available for using the date/time/calendar/alarm functions.

---

The basic [**Arduino Uno**](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno) for instance uses the Atmel [ATmega328](http://www.atmel.com/Images/8271s.pdf) microcontroller, and exposes 14 digital IO pins - thus supporting up to 14 LEDs directly off digital IO, more through various means such as adding an LED controller or multiplexer. Of the digital IO pins, 6 have native PWM support, usable for LED dimming.

The ATmega328 has two 8-bit and one 16-bit timer. Of these, Timer 0 (8-bit) is best not used for applications, as it is internally used by the Arduino base code for functions like  `millis()`.

---

If a larger number of LEDs are to be directly programmed, or more timers are required, the [**Arduino Mega 2560**](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560), based on the [ATmega2560](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2549.pdf) MCU, exposes 54 digital IO pins, 15 of them with native PWM support that can be used for LED dimming.

The ATmega2560 has two 8-bit and four 16-bit timers, and again the Timer 0 caveat applies.

---

*Without additional detail on the specific design requirements, a specific Arduino recommendation is not feasible.*